# Create a user and assign to him a group

Tags: python, json, django, tastypie

First attempt to create a user:

```
data = {
    "username": "johndoe",
    "first_name": "john",
    "last_name": "doe",
    "email": "john@doe.com.br"
}
```

***ApiFieldError: The 'groups' field has no data and doesn't allow a null value.***
 ***"POST /api/v1/user/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 500 ***

2nd attempt to create a user

```
data = {
    "username": "johndoe",
    "first_name": "john",
    "last_name": "doe",
    "email": "johndoe@jd.com",
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "GroupTest"
        }
    ]
}
```

***NotFound: An incorrect URL was provided 'n' for the 'GroupResource' resource.***
***"POST /api/v1/user/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 500***

In both attempts the user was created.
Producing the following results:

> :8000/api/v1/user/?format=json

```
{
    "date_joined": "2014-11-12T14:02:00",
    "email": "john@doe.com.br",
    "first_name": "john",
    "groups": [],
    "id": 22,
    "is_active": true,
    "is_staff": false,
    "is_superuser": false,
    "last_login": "2014-11-12T14:02:00",
    "last_name": "doe",
    "resource_uri": "/api/v1/user/22/",
    "username": "johndoe"
}

{
    "date_joined": "2014-11-12T14:15:20",
    "email": "johndoe@jd.com",
    "first_name": "john",
    "groups": [],
    "id": 24,
    "is_active": true,
    "is_staff": false,
    "is_superuser": false,
    "last_login": "2014-11-12T14:15:20",
    "last_name": "doe",
    "resource_uri": "/api/v1/user/24/",
    "username": "johndoe"
}
```

If I create the user in django-admin the result is this:

```
{
    "date_joined": "2014-11-12T14:13:47",
    "email": "johndoe@jd.com",
    "first_name": "john",
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "GroupTest",
            "permissions": [], # //9 items
            "resource_uri": "/api/v1/groups/1/"
        }
    ],
        "id": 23,
        "is_active": true,
        "is_staff": false,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "last_login": "2014-11-12T14:13:47",
        "last_name": "doe",
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/user/23/",
        "username": "johndoe"
}
```

How could I create a user by api, associating him to a existent group? Like when i do it by django-admin?

Comment: `POST /api/v1/user/?format=json` are you sure this is correct? It looks really weird

Comment: Its always works fine